# Triggering popup.isopen = closed from different view?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am looking for a way to close a popup created in MainPage from a button in a usercontrol I created. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found a good way in the ApplicationSettings example from Microsoft.

```
        Popup parent = this.Parent as Popup;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.IsOpen = false;
        }
```